# -webkit-overflow-scrolling issues in iOS7

Tags: css, mobile-safari, mobile-website, ios7.1, smooth-scrolling

I'm using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` on a `<div>` containing `<ul>` element. This `<ul>` may have some complex `<li>` elements including multiple `<div>`'s with position absolute (used for sipe touch gestures) or `<li>` items with  elements inside (for text input).

This css property interferes with the touch events:

1. Text that is written in the input is not showing (any action that refreshes the DOM "fixes" this
2. unwanted horizontal scroll appears ("overlow-x: hidden" is ignored).

Anyone knows how to overcome this?